# Cropped image is bigger than inteded size in pixels in coppit.js

Tags: javascript, css, django

I am using [cropit.js](http://scottcheng.github.io/cropit/) to crop images in my django app. I have defined the width and height of the image in pixels since the size matters mostly in my app. However the cropped image appears to be bigger than the size i defined.

Heres how i defined the size of the image:

```
$('.image-editor').cropit({
      exportZoom: 1.25,
      imageBackground: true,
      imageBackgroundBorderWidth: 20,
      width:227,
      height:290 ,
```

This function will override the css properties. I want images of size `227*290` but i kept getting the image of bigger size. What am i doing wrong?? Help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went through the documentation and maybe skipped a part or two. Theres a method called `exportZoom` which  when defined will output the image size as per the defined value. That right there was where i went wrong.